# Django - How to display a matrix of data, with sums at the end of each row and column

Tags: python, django, matrix

OK - so what I'm actually trying to display is a consolidated balance sheet for a company that uses fund accounting.

But for simplicity, I'll use an analogy.

Let's say that a group of people are going for a road trip. The leader says to each person, "Give me a list of all the groceries you want me to buy for the trip". All the people who want to go hand him their list. From that list, the leader puts together a master-list, from which to go grocery shopping.

There are two main unknowns:

1. How many people are going on the trip, and thus providing a list
2. What items (and quantities) will be on each list

For example, lets say two people are providing lists, they might look like this:

**Person A**:

- 4 Apples
- 6 Bananas
- 1 Box of Crackers

**Person B**:

- 2 Bananas
- 4 Oranges
- 1 Watermelon

From these two lists, the leader must produce a list like this:

```
      Person      A  B  Total
                ------------
Apples            4  0   4
Bananas           6  2   8
Oranges           0  4   4
Watermelon        0  1   1
----------------------------
    **Fruit**    10  7  17

Box of Crackers   1  0   1
----------------------------
    **Other**     1  0   1
```

You can see the final list is a matrix with totals for each item (rows) but then totals again for each main category (fruit/other). With the two unknowns (People/items) this matrix can have any number of people (columns) and any number of items (rows). Also, the list is grouped into "Fruits" and "Other", with totals within those groups.

I need to figure out how to display this kind of data (but for accounting). I've tried using lists, where I put all the items for Person A into one list, all the items for Person B into another list, then iterate over the lists on my Django Template, but that doesn't work all that well.

I can imagine there are multiple ways to solve this, I'm just not sure what the most efficient method would be knowing that there could be many "people" and many "items" for each master list.

Again, this is actually for displaying a consolidated balance sheet for a company using fund accounting. Thus the "People" are actually the Funds and the "Grocery Items" are actually the accounts within each fund. Not every fund has the same accounts as the other funds.

**Edit**

For clarity, I'm modeling this like so:

```
model Person
  field: persons_name

model ItemType:
  field: i_types #Things like "Fruit", "Veggies", "Canned Goods", etc.

model Item
  field: item_name
  FK: ItemType


model Selection
  FK: Person
  FK: Item
  field: qty
```

**Edit 2** Added more fields to my models

Comment: How are you matching Banana's of person A to Banana's of person B? Is there a many-to-many relationship or is it just a list for each person and items are matched by name?

Comment: @hashemi They are mutually exclusive to one another. However, for the purpose of "buying the groceries" the leader needs to know the total bananas to buy. In other words, the list of items for person A is completely separate from the list of items for person B. There is no connection data-wise between the number of bananas for person A and the number of Bananas for person B. They need to stay separate. But we *do* need to know the grand total.

Comment: @hashemi Hmm, not sure I answered your question. Data storage wise, I might have a model `Item` to hold types of items (Bananas, Apples, Box of Crackers) then another model to associate the people with their selection, like `PeopleSelection` with `FK = Item`, `field=PersonName`, and `field = qty`. Hope that clarifies a bit.

Comment: @Garfonzo Similar to hashemi's question: How do you model item categories: a separate model for categories or just a field for their names on the item model?

Comment: @schwobaseggl Added some clarification

Comment: @Garfonzo Ok, that still leaves the question: how do you know that an `Item` with `item_name` *banana* is a **Fruit**

Comment: @schwobaseggl Great point - I have a "category" field in my `Item` model. Remember, this is all an analogy, and the real models are all accounting related. So, instead of `Item` I have `Account` and the clasification `AccountType` for Asset, Liability, Equity, etc. I'll update my question though.

Answer (score 3):

You should avoid doing anything else than presentation in the templates. My suggestion is that you build a few convenient data structures in your view and just iterate over them in the template:

- a `list` of "Persons" (to create the table header)
- a `dictionary` of items, where the item is the key (you can use the string representation of the item to keep things simpler) and the value is an ordered list of items in the same order the list at the previous point is ordered; you could also append the total to this list.

This makes it easier to work with things in the template, you'd have something like:

```
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Item name</td>
            {% for person in person_list %}
                <td>{{ person.name }}</td>
            {% endfor %}
            <td>Total</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        {% for item, item_list in item_dict.items %}
            <tr>
                <td>{{ item }}</td>
                {% for i in item_list %}
                    <td>{{ i }}</td>
                {% endfor %}
            </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    <tbody>
</table>
```

In order to integrate your categories, the `dictionary` structure can be further nested in a category `dictionary` that has data (the dict above) and also a list of totals.

**Bottom line to what I'm suggesting is that you should build all your structures inside your view in such a way that displaying them is a breeze in the template, and not the other way around**

Comment: Yes, I agree - build everything inside a view, then just iterate. The challenge is (I think) in creating the Totals. I have totals at the end of each line for each item (total bananas, total apples, etc.). Then I have totals for each person for the group. So, total number of **Fruit** for Person A, total number o **Fruit** for person B. Then again for the rest of the categories -- "Other" in my example above. I think, as you suggested, the iteration over the pre-built data is easy. The challenge is the totals for each item for **all** people, then for the categories for **each** person.

Comment: How about building an additional `category_totals` dict with `People` as key and totals as values?

Answer (score 0):

I made a [working example](https://github.com/hashemi/django-matrix-so-answer) as per your models. Here are excerpts with explanations.

This is what your view would look like:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from .models import *

def index(request):
  all_selections = Selection.objects.all()
  all_people = set([selection.person for selection in all_selections])
  blank_person_counts = {person: 0 for person in all_people}
  all_categories = set([selection.item.category for selection in all_selections])

  categories = []

  for category in all_categories:
    selections = [s for s in all_selections if s.item.category == category]

    total_by_person = blank_person_counts.copy()

    unique_item_details = set([s.item for s in selections])

    items = [{'detail': item_details} for item_details in unique_item_details]
    total_by_item = {item['detail']: 0 for item in items}
    total_by_item_person = {item['detail']: blank_person_counts.copy() for item in items}

    for selection in selections:
      total_by_item_person[selection.item][selection.person] = selection.quantity
      total_by_item[selection.item] += selection.quantity
      total_by_person[selection.person] += selection.quantity

    for item in items:
      item['people_totals'] = [total_by_item_person[item['detail']][person] for person in all_people]
      item['total'] = total_by_item[item['detail']]

    people_totals = [total_by_person[person] for person in all_people]
    category_total = sum(people_totals)

    categories.append({
      'detail': category.name,
      'people_totals': people_totals,
      'total': category_total,
      'items': items
    })

  context = {'people': all_people, 'categories': categories}
  return render(request, 'matrix.html', context)
```

I started by getting `all_selections` because I assumed if an item was never selected or if a person never selected a category, they shouldn't be included, so the selections are the core of the data.

From the obtained selections, I generated a list of people (`all_people`). Having this defined before we go into items helps us make sure that every person is accounted for in each item. Even if a person didn't select an item, we will assign them a quantity of zero for that item. It also sets the order in which people are displayed as columns and we will use the same order when returning totals by people for each item and for each category.

Since the data is divided by category, we generate a list of categories from the list of selections. We then loop over each category, filter selections by that category, create a blank slate in which each item was selected by each person zero times. When then go over the actual selections and update the counts with the quantities. We also maintain running totals per person per category. In the end, we sum up the running totals per person as that will be the grand total for the category. We repeat the same process for each category.

In the template, it's basically a matter of looping over this data and displaying it:

```
<h1>The Grocery Matrix</h1>

<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    {% for person in people %}
      <th>{{ person }}</th>
    {% endfor %}
    <th>Total</th>
  </tr>

  {% for category in categories %}
    {% for item in category.items %}
    <tr>
      <td>{{ item.detail }}</td>
      {% for person_total_for_item in item.people_totals %}
        <td>{{ person_total_for_item }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
      <td>{{ item.total }}</td>
    </tr>
    {% endfor %}


    <tr>
      <td>{{ category.detail }}</td>
      {% for person_total_for_category in category.people_totals %}
        <td>{{ person_total_for_category }}</td>
      {% endfor %}
      <td>{{ category.total }}</td>
    </tr>

  {% endfor %}
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Nice - thanks for this. I had something similar, but I think I was getting all caught up in looping and thought I was missing something logic-wise (hence the post to SO). I'll see about implementing something similar to this on my project.

Comment: Just added a link to a complete GitHub project.